# Force redirect to login when accessing website page odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I need to force the user to be authenticated when accessing a static page as part of the website module so far what I've done is this:

```
class RestrictAreas(Home):
    @http.route(['/page1','/page2'],type="http", auth='user', website=True)
    def test(self):
        website_page = request.env['ir.http']._serve_page()
        return website_page
```

it works for page1 and page2 but I need it to be as dynamic, so that controller intercepts any HTTP request for a web page and validates the user.

Can I use a regex for a slug or something similar?
I am overriding the right method in the controller?

thanks in advvance.

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite `_serve_page()` function in `ir.http` and check if the user is logged in or redirect to login page you don't need to build a custom controller for it, this will handle any static page request and you can build another function for your custom controllers

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit more?